# Idol hidden in the Kaaba?

Tags: sources-mekorot, avodah-zarah, islam

Which rabbi(s) wrote that there were idols hidden inside the Kaaba (Muslim direction of prayer), thus making Islam Avodah Zarah? *(Whether the rabbi(s) were mistaken or not is besides the point)*

I recall someone quoting a rabbi stating the abovementioned statement on this site, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: The rabbi wasn't mistaken. The Moslims admit there were idols. Actually, Islam is still idolatry.

Comment: @TurkHill I meant that a Rabbi said that there was still an idol hidden within the Kaaba even after the Muslims destroyed them

Comment: Mmmm. Perhaps he meant Islam is still hidden in the Kaaba since Islam is idolatry?

Comment: @TurkHill I'm almost certain he was referring to a physical idol

Comment: Perhaps your right.

Answer (score 1):

The Rambam quotes this view (Teshuvot Harambam ed. Mekitsei Nirdamim [369](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1733&st=&pgnum=402&hilite=)). He doesn't name the source of the view, and he himself doesn't support or reject the fact itself.

> ואם יאמר אדם שהבית שהם מקלסין אותו בית ע"ז הוא וע"ז צפונה בתוכו שהיו עובדין אותה אבותיהם מה בכך. אלו המשתחוים כנגדו היום אין לבם אלא לשמים
>
> If someone were to say that the house that they praise [God] in is a house of idol worship, and an idol that their ancestors worshiped is hidden in it, what does it matter? Those who bow down towards it today direct their hearts only to heaven.